# Convenient way to copy & paste links to uploaded file attachments when editing Drupal 7 content?

Tags: 7, files

In Drupal 6, when enabled, the upload module presents a handy list of all the files attached to a Page node.  The list includes the file URL in plain text for convenient copy & paste into the Page node body.  E.g.

[image: D6 Upload Module Listing]

Drupal 7 replaced the upload module functionality with file fields in core.  The listing provided by this functionality does not display the file URL.  E.g.

[image: D7 File Attachment Listing]

How can I conveniently copy and paste the file URL using this Drupal 7 method?

Note: Right-click + Copy file location is *not convenient* because you end up with extra overlay related information on your URL.  Furthermore, you also always get the full URL instead of just the parts you want (i.e. relative link).

Answer (score 1):

IMCE will let users browse to it and insert links to the files inside a text area if that's what you're going for. You could also programmatically alter the form and provide a copy to clipboard link next to the file in the listing.